# Approximation of a quadratic form

Tags: approximation, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. Also, let $Q\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be the quadratic form given by
$$
Q(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}.
$$
By definition, the above quadratic form can be computed using the double sum,
$$
Q(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}x_ix_j,
$$
which is expensive for my purposes... Could anyone suggest any approximation that may be executed faster than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$? Thanks!

Comment: Unless the matrix $A$ is sparse, there will be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ unique elements in $A$. It seems that you would need to have $O(n^2)$ to compute the quadratic form.

Comment: @robjohn, yes, so there's no approach that could be faster? I though of Cholesky factorization, in order to keep some of the more important dimensions, but the factorization itself takes $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$...

Comment: unless the matrix $A$ has some special properties, I don't see how the computation could be better than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @robjohn, yes, I guess you're right... I asked the question just in case someone knew something I ignore... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just because I don't see anything, doesn't mean someone else won't. Wait and see.